# Not understanding example of a Pushdown Automata

Tags: automata, pushdown-automata

The first example of a (nondeterministic) pushdown automata given in Linz' *An Introduction to Formal Languages and Automata* is the following:

**Example 7.2:** consider

- $Q = \{q_0,q_1,q_2,q_3\}$,
- $\Sigma = \{a,b\}$,
- $\Gamma = \{0,1\}$,
- $z = 0$,
- $F = \{q_3\}$,

with $q_0$ the initial state and

- $\delta (q_0,a,0) = \{(q_1,10),(q_3,\lambda)\}$,
- $\delta (q_0,\lambda,0) = \{(q_3,\lambda)\}$,
- $\delta (q_1,a,1) = \{(q_1,11)\}$,
- $\delta (q_1,b,1) = \{(q_2,\lambda)\}$,
- $\delta (q_2,b,1) = \{(q_2,\lambda)\}$,
- $\delta (q_2,\lambda,0) = \{(q_3,\lambda)\}$.

The author states

> The crucial transitions are
> $$δ (q_1, a, 1) = \{(q_1, 11)\},$$
> which adds a $1$ to the stack when an $a$ is read, and
> $$δ (q_2, b, 1) = \{(q_2, λ)\},$$
> which removes a $1$ when a $b$ is encountered. These two steps count the number of $a$’s and match that count against the number of $b$’s.

---

***How does the automata count the number of $a$'s and $b$'s?***

What *exactly* does the transition $δ (q_1, a, 1) = \{(q_1, 11)\}$ do to the stack? If the transition is crucial in counting the $a$'s, then I'd imagine it 'enqueues' another $1$ into the stack e.g. the stack goes from $110...$ to $1110...$

However, I fail to see how the formal definition of the pushdown automata would keep track of the stack, as we are only given the stack alphabet $\Gamma$ and the stack starting symbol $z$, so the information regarding what the stack contains at each point in time is not 'saved'.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question. There is a finite set of control states $Q$ (which can actually be eliminated without losing the expressive power of a PDA) and a stack. Both together yield a state or configuration $(q, \gamma)$, where $\gamma \in \Gamma^\ast$ is the stack content. Every transition involves reading the next symbol of the input (or $\lambda$ / $\varepsilon$) and the top of the stack and replacing control state by a different state and the top of the stack by a word.

Answer (score 1):

the stack is kept track of by a so called "configuration".
Imagine, that the configuration represents a complete description of your machine at a point in time.
The transition function only needs to tell you, how the configuration might *change* during the computation.

For a PDA $A = (Q, \Sigma, \Gamma, \delta, q_0, z, F)$, a config needs to keep track of the current state, remaining input, and stack.
So a config is a 3-tuple
$$(q, u, v)$$
where $q \in Q$ is a state, $u \in \Sigma^*$ is the remaining input and $v \in \Gamma^*$ is the stack.
Now
$$\delta(q, a, v) \ni (q', v')$$
can be read as "if in state $q$ you read $a$ and your stack top is $v$, you might change to state $q'$ by popping $v$ and pushing $v'$".
Using our configs we can write
$$(q, au, vs) \vdash (q', u, v's) \iff \delta(q, a, v) \ni (q', v')$$
where $C \vdash C'$ represents one step in the computation, the machine changes from $C$ to $C'$ in one step.
So a computation for $aaabbb$ in your example machine might look something like this:

- $(q_0, aaabbb, 0) \vdash (q_1, aabbb, 10)$
- $(q_1, aabbb, 10) \vdash (q_1, abbb, 110)$
- $(q_1, abbb, 110) \vdash (q_1, bbb, 1110)$
- $(q_1, bbb, 1110) \vdash (q_2, bb, 110)$
- $(q_2, bb, 110) \vdash (q_2, b, 10)$
- $(q_2, b, 10) \vdash (q_2, \lambda, 0)$
- $(q_2, \lambda, 0) \vdash (q_3, \lambda, \lambda)$

We say that the PDA accepts $w \in \Sigma^*$ iff $(q_0, w, z) \vdash^* (q_f, \lambda, \lambda)$ and $q_f \in F$, so your PDA accepts $aaabbb$.

Hope that helps :]